# Custom Scrollbars that works across all Browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to integrate custom scrollbars to table tag in my html page. Main requirement the scroll bars are cross browser compatible and fulfill the following conditions as well

1. Only Horizontal scroll bars will appear if the rows are below 50 and
   the columns are more than 30
2. Only Vertical scroll bars will appear, if the columns are not more than 30 and the rows are more than 50.
3. Both the scroll bars will appear in remaining cases.
4. In a page we  can have more one table tag.

I tried the following plugins none of them are not fulfilled all the above conditions

1. Flexcroll : www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar
   When we placing two tables scroll bars are not working
2. rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll
    Both the scrollbars are not working
3. www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/
    Bothe the scrollbars are not working

please suggest a plugin or css script for this